# Cannot read property 'google' of undefined

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, undefined

I am trying to write a function to see if a user has logged in with either google or facebook and depending on the choice of the user I then want to display the correct name when logged in.

This is the current github project I am working on: https://github.com/simgul-1/modus

I have  simplified my code but I have something similar in header.ejs which is included in almost all pages (I am using ejs templates):

```
        <% if (user.google.name) { %>

            <%= user.google.name %> 

            <% } else if (user.facebook.name) { %>

                <%= user.facebook.name %> 

            <% } else { %>
                <form class="navbar-right">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <a class="btn btn-danger" href="/auth/google">Google</a>
                        <a class="btn btn-info" href="/auth/facebook">Facebook</a>
                    </ul>
                </form>
        <% } %>
```

The problem is that it can find user `user` but not anything below.
The schema for the model is defined as followed:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    facebook         : {
        id           : String,
        token        : String,
        email        : String,
        name         : String
    },
    google           : {
        id           : String,
        token        : String,
        email        : String,
        name         : String
    }

});
```

Most of the routes.js file looks something like this:

```
    app.get('/somepage', function(req, res) {
    res.render('pages/somepage.ejs', {
        user : req.user
    });
});
```

Comment: Please show us the code that renders that view - what are you passing to it, what is your find() command etc?

Comment: I am using ejs templates and the code above is included in every page since its a header.